# Tableau Extract from a view instead of postgres or mysql table

Tags: extract, tableau-api

Can tableau extract data from a postgres/ mysql view instead of a table.

Comment: can we consider this question as answered? if so, please accept the answer in order to "close" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Table or view doesn't make any difference for Tableau in terms of connection.

Just remember that while tables need only the "read" part, views need the computation part too in order to retrieve data.

Basically you will get longer time for extract or live results.